# Chrome Extension Blob data issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, blob

I am trying to create a blob from a canvas image from within a Chrome extension, however I am getting an error "**Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function**" when trying to create a Blob using any method!

```
var blob = new Blob();
var blob = new Blob(['body { color: red; }'], {type: 'text/css'});
```

are two examples that fail with the above error. I am actually trying to convert a DataURL to a blob so the code I am using (which also fails) is...

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    'use strict'
    var byteString, 
        mimestring 

    if(dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') !== -1 ) {
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1])
    } else {
        byteString = decodeURI(dataURI.split(',')[1])
    }

    mimestring = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    var content = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        content[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
    }

    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(content)], {type: mimestring});
}
```

I am assuming that Chrome will not support new blobs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the call to create a Blob was being done from a JS file, the correct place was the background JavaScript file. By moving the method to create the blob into the background file I as able to use it.